# CORS for spring boot not in response header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I tried implementing the GLOBAL CORS as suggested by this spring site for my spring boot Applications which gets deployed to Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

However, when I send OPTIONS message to the service end point, The response does not return any CORS headers in it. So, application fails to make POST call after preflight. Here is my implementation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CORSConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("*/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS")
            .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "Authorization")
            .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: In which package is this class located, relative to the main/SpringBoot starter class?

Comment: main/springboot start class is in this package:     com.gm.cei.lbs.callpoint      
while CORSconfig is in this package :  com.gm.cei.lbs.callpoint.configuration

Comment: I moved the class in the same package as the main/spring boot start class, made no difference.

Comment: Your configuration for CORS is correct. Do you include "origin" header in your requests?

Comment: Yes. I tried sending request with or without Origin header. I used http://localhost:8080 as Origin value. no luck getting all required headers back. Also, never see the maxAge taking any effect in my response headers. Also, please note that we have custom security in place for spring end points which uses basic authentication.

Comment: Also, tries using the CrossOrigin annotation  at controller level   Controller
CrossOrigin(origins="*", methods={RequestMethod.OPTIONS,RequestMethod.POST},
    allowedHeaders={"Content-Type","Authorization"},
    maxAge=3600)       This did not work either..

Comment: I tried disabling the security, still no luck getting the CORS header in OPTIONS response.

Answer (score 6):

Ok. I found where the problem was. HTTP OPTIONS request alone does not constitute the pre-flight request. In order for OPTIONS to be considered pre-flight request, it needs 2 more request headers. one is Origin, which I added to the request. However, what i missed was on the Access-Control-Request-Method. Pre-flight request generated by browsers would have all 3 http request headers in it. Once i added all 3 request headers, I saw my CORS headers coming back in the response.

Here is the sample code and response.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CORSConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("POST")
            .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "Authorization")
            .allowCredentials(false)
            .maxAge(32400);  // 9 hours max age
    }
}
```

Here is the request :

```
OPTIONS /my-end-point HTTP/1.1
Host: my-app.my-domain.com
Origin: http://localhost:8090
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bc7171bc-7f84-3b44-a304-818627411a72
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Here is the response.

```
access-control-allow-methods →POST
access-control-allow-origin →*
access-control-max-age →32400
```